# How can i make a timecount from an epoch specific time? jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, epoch

i get the time through a json, like this

```
"timeAddedToDrive": 1398813844020
```

Im wondering if i can create a jQuery or JS that begun a count from that time, so users can see how much time passed since the event happened in seconds like

```
event was 48:05 minutes ago...
```

Its that posible?

PD: apologies about my english, i know its pretty bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

You can use this library to convert date values from various storage formats into others including human-readable descriptions like you are looking for.

The function `.fromNow()` is close to what you are looking for but it is probably not precise enough.  With a little bit more effort you can use `moment.js` to determine the `diff` of timestamp relative to now, convert that to `duration` and then get the minutes and seconds from the duration.

```
var timeAddedToDrive = 1398813844020;

var now = moment();
var timePassed = now.diff(timeAddedToDrive);

// fromNow function works but is not precise
alert( moment(timeAddedToDrive).fromNow());

// for more precision we'll get the minutes and seconds from the DURATION
var seconds = moment.duration(timePassed).seconds(); 
var minutes = moment.duration(timePassed).minutes(); 
var output = "event was " +
    minutes.toString() + ":" + 
    seconds.toString() + " minutes ago"

alert( output );
```

Here's a jsFiddle that shows both approaches: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83er9/3/)

Hope that helps.